# Why doesn't this function detect overlapping circles?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

http://jsfiddle.net/goldrunt/SeAGU/52/
Line 49 checks for "false" on isOnCircle function before creating the new object. Function is on line 32. When creating more object, the function is passing when it should not pass.

```
 if (isOnCanvas(location) && !isOnCircle(location)) {
        console.log(location, isOnCanvas(location), isOnCircle(location));
        create(location);
```

In fact I can't get the collision detection to register true no matter what values are passed to it

```
(Math.pow((a.x - i.x), 2) + Math.pow((a.y - i.y), 2) <= Math.pow((a.radius + i.radius), 2))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here I've fixed and given more descriptive variable names so you can see what's going on.
EDIT: I've noticed you don't always feed a circle but sometimes a point as A, which does not have a .radius property resulting in NaN, which also screws up your comparison.

```
function circleTest(a,b) {
    var DistanceX = a.x - b.x;
    var DistanceY = a.y - b.y;
    var DistanceCenter = Math.sqrt(DistanceX * DistanceX + DistanceY * DistanceY);
    var CollisionDistance = b.radius;
    if (a.radius) CollisionDistance += a.radius
    return DistanceCenter <= CollisionDistance;
}
```

I also noticed a problem in your function called "isOnCircle" where you are using i (a number) as if it were a circle object, with the above function this can be fixed like:

```
function isOnCircle(a) {
    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        if (circleTest(a, circles[i])) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't feed a circle object to "circleTest" because it hasn't been created yet. This is a test to see if it will be pushed at all based on the click location. Correct? Did you include the +=a.radius just in case there is no radius? How could that happen?

Comment: Because in your code you do isOnCircle(location), so that ends up doing circleTest(location, ...) and location.radius does not exist! That was one of the problems in the original code. --- I believe from playing your game that you _do_ want to give location a radius, because without a radius you can click so close to a circle that it overlaps when it spawns.

Comment: Eventually, the circles will expand on mousedown and stop when colliding with other circles or the borders. They shouldn't overlap at all on creation, though. One step at a time. This is one of my first projects. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

- `i` is the numerical index you are using to iterate through the `circles` array but you are using it as if it was a circle object; you need to use `circles[i]` to get the circle at each iteration.
- `a` is a point and does not have a radius (in the code below I've left `a.radius` in just in-case you pass in a circle rather than a point and have `OR`ed it with 0 so you get a valid number).

Defining some additional variables (for clarity) then you can replace the `isOnCircle` function with this:

```
function isOnCircle(a) {
    var i=0,l=circles.length,x,y,d,c;
    for (; i < l; ++i) {
        c = circles[i];
        x = a.x-c.x;
        y = a.y-c.y;
        d = (a.radius||0)+c.radius;
        if (x*x+y*y <= d*d) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was a silly mistake to use i instead of circles[i]...Also is it necessary to declare all vars in JS as in line 2?

Comment: BTW I updated to d=(a.radius||10)+c.radius to account for initial radius of 10px. They still overlapped otherwise. Does that make sense?

Comment: No it's not necessary, but it's a good habit for keeping your code clean. Or maybe that's just the old school C in me talking.

Comment: @MattO - the main reason for declaring the variables on line 2 rather than inside the loop is that there is the potential for the JavaScript interpreter to allocate new memory each time the variable is allocated. If you do it outside the loop then this is only one allocation but inside the loop there is the potential for many re-allocations (and garbage collections) which will result in  a performance hit. Hopefully the interpreter is clever enough not to do this but just to try and make sure I will declare variables outside of loops if possible/appropriate.